# Rails: ActiveAdmin doesn't work with Friendly_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, friendly-id

I have ActiveAdmin set up to manage the users on the site, and Friendly_id for readable urls. When I go to /admin/users, it throws this error:

```
Undefined method `per' for #<User::FriendlyIdActiveRecordRelation:0x007fdb61a38d30>
```

How friendly_id is set up in the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

The only resource I could find for the conflict between these 2 gems is this question [ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord when using ActiveAdmin and Friendly_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684644/activerecordreadonlyrecord-when-using-activeadmin-and-friendly-id) which seems like a different issue and the solution doesn't work in my case. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it's actually not the problem with `friendly_id` but with `will_paginate` as mentioned here https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/670. Switching to `kaminari` for pagination solves the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it [this way](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#Active_Admin):

> Unless you use the :finders addon, you should modify your admin controllers for models that use FriendlyId with something similar to the following:

```
controller do
  def find_resource
    scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, and found that `friendly_id` overrides the `to_param` method, so just re-override it. it works for me.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  before_filter do
    User.class_eval do
      def to_param
        id.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```