# Def to param with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I use:

```
def to_param
    user_name
end
```

and in my active admin user.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index do
      column :id
      column :email
      column :user_name
      column :created_at
      default_actions
  end
end
```

That of course gives me an `Couldn't find User with id=testuser`

How can i specify to Active Admin to use this properly ?

**Edit 1**: With the answer below it works but def to param get's overwritten on all the app..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684644/activerecordreadonlyrecord-when-using-activeadmin-and-friendly-id

Comment: Sweet, worked.. Mind Answering so i can upvote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job in the app/admin/user.rb :

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  before_filter :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy] do
    @user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to override the default finder:

```
controller do
  defaults :finder => :find_by_user_name
end
```

Comment: this is best answer indeed

Answer (score 1):

Override the to_param implementation for ActiveAdmin

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foobar do
  before_filter do
    Foobar.class_eval do
      def to_param
        id.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684644/activerecordreadonlyrecord-when-using-activeadmin-and-friendly-id) for more info/alternate solution related to this topic

Comment: Hey vimsha, although it works with Active Admin, INAPP all def to params are overwritten to :id and nothing works... Is there a viable Solution to this ?