# ActiveAdmin with friendly id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am using `friendly_id` in my rails 4 application with `slug`. Now I am using [active_admin gem](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin).

**Problem:**

When I click on show link from active admin for `Group` resource, It is throwing the following exception:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /admin/groups/username20-s-group-1
```

I guess, I need to override some of the `active_admin` default functions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are cases, when application has quit a few resources, hence in order to keep it DRY there is a nice solution requiring few lines of code for whole application - simply override activeadmin's resource controller.

Create `config/initializers/active_admin_monkey_patching.rb` file with the following content:

```rb
ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.class_eval do
  def find_resource
    finder = resource_class.is_a?(FriendlyId) ? :slug : :id
    scoped_collection.find_by(finder => params[:id])
  end
end
```

Do not forget to restart the server.

Comment: I think it has to be added in `config/intializers/active_admin.rb` . Worked for me when I added it there.  `Friendly_id - 5.1`

Comment: Shouldn't matter which initializer it gets added in.

Answer (score 21):

A better approach to @AndreyDeineko's is to override `ActiveAdmin::ResourceController`'s `find_resource` method in `config/initialisers/active_admin.rb` and leverage the methods provided by FriendlyId (5.x at this point):

In `config/initialisers/active_admin.rb`:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  # == Friendly Id addon
  ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.class_eval do
    def find_resource
      if resource_class.is_a?(FriendlyId)
        scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
      else
        scoped_collection.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
  # initial config
end
```

This looks much cleaner to me, than putting it in the application controller, as it is related to the configuration of Active Admin.

Comment: Getting problem with starting Puma: `=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.4 application starting in development 
=> Run 'bin/rails server --help' for more startup options
Exiting
[...]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activeadmin-2.13.1/lib/active_admin/base_controller/authorization.rb:3:in '<module:ActiveAdmin>': uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base (NameError)

  class BaseController < ::InheritedResources::Base
                                             ^^^^^^
Did you mean?  Base64` any ideas?

Comment: @JensSchmidt Happy to see I'm not the only one. I may be a bit late to this party, but I believe I've found a workaround to that particular issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74916805/2288659

Answer (score 6):

Found solution for the problem:

In your `app/admin/[ResourceName.rb]` add:

```
  # app/admin/group.rb

  # find record with slug(friendly_id)
  controller do
    def find_resource
      begin
        scoped_collection.where(slug: params[:id]).first!
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        scoped_collection.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you've tried some of the other answers here and gotten

```
uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base (NameError)
```

Then you might consider monkey patching `FriendlyId` rather than `ActiveAdmin`. Create a new initializer file `config/initializers/friendly_id_monkey_patch.rb` containing this:

```rb
module FriendlyIdModelMonkeyPatch

  def to_param
    if caller.to_s.include? 'active_admin'
      id&.to_s
    else
      super
    end
  end

end

module FriendlyId::Model
  prepend FriendlyIdModelMonkeyPatch
end
```

Now all of your `FriendlyId` models will revert to using their ID in ActiveAdmin and their slug everywhere else.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36071769/2288659), which does the same thing but for only one model (rather than monkey patching for all `FriendlyId` models)

Answer (score 0):

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, :use => [:slugged, :finders]
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's suboptimal to completely override the `find_resource` as most of the answers suggest. Better to prepend a module and call `super` preserving normal behaviour when FriendlyId is not in use. For reference you can check how this method is currently (as of writing) implemented, it is not simply `scoped_collection.find(params[:id])` as one might think:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/b45b1fb05af9a7f6c5e2be94f61cf4a5f60ff3bb/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L104

```
module ActiveAdminFriendlyIdScoping
  def find_resource
    if resource_class.is_a? FriendlyId
      scoped_collection.friendly.find params[:id]
      # Or potentially even
      # scoped_collection.friendly.send method_for_find, params[:id]
      # Or you could do something like this
      # raise "Using FriendlyId, find method configuration ignored" if method_for_find != :find
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  #...
  Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
    ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.prepend(ActiveAdminFriendlyIdScoping)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Really late to the party here, but we were struggling recently with this in a Rails 7.0 app and I wanted to share our fix.

If you see the `uninitialized constant InheritedResources::Base (NameError)` error, put your `class_eval` block inside an `after_initialize` block in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`.

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.class_eval do
      def find_resource
        finder = resource_class.is_a?(FriendlyId) ? :slug : :id
        scoped_collection.find_by(finder => params[:id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This works because it will overwrite `#find_resource` after Rails has initialized instead of in the middle of it while other classes have not loaded yet.