# rails how to use friendly_id only in frontend not in admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I only want to use friendly_id generated slug in frontend not in admin. How to accomplished this?

in my admin controller:

```
def find_data
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
```

in my frontend controller:

```
def set_data
    @product = current_user.products.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Both code still return the same result (using friendly_id generated slug)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

extend FriendlyId

friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders, :history]

private

def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    new_record? || slug.blank? || name_changed?
  end
```

anybody can help? thanks

**UPDATE**

I found the way to do this in AciveAdmin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684644/activerecordreadonlyrecord-when-using-activeadmin-and-friendly-id). But Im not using ActiveAdmin

Answer (score 2):

The only solution is to not override the `to_param` model method, but instead create a parallel method that outputs the slug when called.

Then, explicitly call this method where you need it on the public side. Or you can do the opposite, and default `to_param` to the friendly id and explicitly pass the ID in the admin section when generating a route.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use friendly_id slug. Just use this in your code:

```
<%= link_to(product.name, admin_product_path(product.id)) %>
```

instead of:

```
<%= link_to(product.name, admin_product_path(product)) %>
```

I hope it will be useful for anyone who had same question with me